# docstring convert to read me file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation

currently i have project that i need to convert docstring (google) to be in readme file format. the project contains multiple sub root and inside these sub root might be a python file or another folder

I use to do readme file with handsdown package in python and it worked fine but recently this package is no longer going to receive an update so I need to find alternative package.

Can anyone provide me with package that create a readme file for entire project based on docstring. i tried using pdoc but didnt work

[image: some Example of issue im facing in sphinx] The issue is that docstring is not visible

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at [`sphinx-doc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/)? It is the standard way to do this in Python projects

Comment: I tried it but didn’t manage to make it work correctly. Would appreciate if you could guide me or provide me with alternatives package that I can explore. Thank you